# Is there a way to use LocalObjectStorageHelper on a large list of objects with StorageFolders

Tags: c#, uwp

I am trying to use LocalObjectStorageHelper to save and load a large dictionary list thats TValue is a list of objects with StorageFolders within it. I'm successfully saving the list as I'm able to physically open the file it saves, however when trying to load the file It throws the following error:`Unable to find a constructor to use for type Windows.Storage.StorageFolder. A class should either have a default constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor marked with the JsonConstructor attribute.`

I haven't tried a whole lot as fairly deep web search about this issue results with posts from several years ago saying that its not possible to do this.

This is the object that I'm trying to save.

```
class Pack
{
    public StorageFolder Folder { get; set; }
    public BitmapImage Image { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public Pack()
    {
    }
}
```

This is what I'm saving to the file.

```
var helper = new LocalObjectStorageHelper();
Dictionary<string, List<Pack>> allpacks = new Dictionary<string, List<Pack>>();
await helper.SaveFileAsync(PackCacheKey, allpacks);
```

Finally this is how I'm trying to load the saved file.

```
var helper = new LocalObjectStorageHelper();
if (await helper.FileExistsAsync(PackCacheKey))
{
    var cachedPacks = await helper.ReadFileAsync<Dictionary<string, List<Pack>>>(PackCacheKey);
}
```

Comment: If you want to save or load a large dictionary list, you'd better not use `StorageFolder` filed directly, you could use folder path to replace.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I looked into that but unfortunately it will not work for my problem. Ive been alternative looking into using StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList  to create a work around.

Comment: Yep, you could also use `FutureAccessList`,   futureAccessList can hold up to 1000 items.
Unlike the MRU, the platform does not manage the futureAccessList for you. When you reach the 1000 item limit, you must remove an item from the list before adding [another one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/hh972603(v=win.10)#preserving-access-to-files-and-folders-beyond-the-25-item-limit).